# How to display thumbs?

Tags: image, filepath

I am new in here.
I have issue how to display thumbs in wallpaper site. I am wondering what is best and fast way to show to my visitor thumb image of a wallpaper. In internet i see that most people use new created thumb of a original image and than they display thumb image. I was wondering is`t faster to make thumb dynamically from original.

Can someone tell me something about this?

Comment: To display thumbs:  Extend thumbs; say, "Eyyyyyyy."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend that when a wallpaper is uploaded that you make thumb, there are code samples for that on the net.
When you display your page, keep in mind that you will load the image you display no matter the size you display it. So say you have 10 images that are 4MB in size (hi res), if you use them as thumbs then you will need to download 40MB of images.
On the other hand if you make thumbs of them (server side on upload) then you will store 20kB per file (average basis) so when showing the page, you'll only download 200kB of images.